# Hyperlinks in Cell Not Emplying Full Use of HTML

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, html, url

The following is on Excel 2013.

I have a spreadsheet that, through a VBA macro, takes a numerical input from a cell and appends it to a hyperlink to a PDF document on a website immediately after "#page="  In theory, this should create a link that will take me to the relevant page on the document.

When clicked, however, the page opens in my browser but does not include the #page= section.  If I right click, Edit Hyperlink, and copy+paste the link there into my browser, however, it takes me to the correct page.  Pasting that same thing into another cell in Excel and clicking once again fails to get the desired result.  Therefore, I assume that my macro creating the link is not the issue here, but it is something with how Excel handles the HTML tag in the link.

Edit:  Upon a little more research, I discovered that Office does not recognize the pound symbol (#) in hyperlinks.  Anyone know any alternative way of getting that to work?

Answer (score 0):

You are correct in the fact that the `#` symbol looking for a `<name>` on a web page in a hyperlink is not accepted as part of the `Address:=` parameter of VBA's `.Hyperlinks.Add` command. However, it can be added in the `SubAddress:=` parameter.

To set a hperlink like [Customize the Quick Access Toolbar - Move the Quick Access Toolbar](http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-HA010362102.aspx#_Toc352651883) you would code like this:

```
ActiveSheet.Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Selection, Address:= _
    "http://office.microsoft.com/en-001/excel-help/customize-the-quick-access-toolbar-HA010362102.aspx" _
    , SubAddress:="_Toc352651883" _
    , TextToDisplay:="Move the Quick Access Toolbar"
```

Click on this for more on the [Hyperlinks.Add Method (Excel)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff822490(v=office.15).aspx)